# condition variable ? with colon

Tags: if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

Here is a snippet of a pseudocode from a friend.

```
int a=50, b=20, c=10;

if (b=(b>a ? a:c))
   c = a - b;
```

What does the code `b>a ? a:c` mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a conditional or ternary Operator.

It's similar to an if-else statement (short hand if Else). 
For example, here `b>a ? a : c` if `b > a` then it returns `a` else it returns `c`.

For more info just google it.